# JQuery Class selector, selecting elements with "-" (hyphen)

Tags: jquery, css, class, selector

I having here a trouble that I cannot understand.

I am updating a website (not written by me) and trying to fix some issues.
Somewhere in the JS script files there is something that adds inline CSS property height in specific element. This needs to be removed.
Already found where it is being executed.

In HTML, I have elements with classes "swipe-control" , "swipe-right" , "swipe-left" and "swipe"

And the only code I have in JS files related to "swipe" is the one below

```
jQuery('.swipe').height(jQuery(window).height());
```

Have changed this to find how many objects were being found :

```
jQuery('.swipe').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).height(jQuery(window).height());            
  console.log(">>>>> ");
  console.log(this);
});
```

All elements with class "swipe-*" are being updated with this height as well.

Is this normal? (Already verified jQuery class selector documentation)

Comment: *"All elements with class "swipe-\*" are being updated with this height as well."* No, they aren't, not by *that* code; not unless they **also** have the class `swipe` (with no `-xyz` after it).

Comment: Nope, does not work that way, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7fuogouj/  Only finds 5 elements.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it stands, this question is missing code to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: If you want to check what matches your jQuery selector (useful for debugging), just `console.log(jQuery('.swipe'))`

Comment: Can you tell us the reason why this inline-styles has to be removed?  If the reason is a SEO perspective than this is not a problem. Because search engines doesn't execute JavaScript code. This inline-style is added in runtime and is not part of the original HTML Document that is parsed by search engines.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the responses.
It is really weird. I wil update the thread with de code tomorrow.

I need to remove the initial height since it is breaking jquery menu "slide up\down" functionality. 
 
Thank you.

Best Regards,
Linton

Answer (score 0):

Check the replication made here according to your description. Do you see, all or more than one div changing its height when clicked on the button labeled "Run"?

If you see more than one div changing its height, then yes, it is abnormal behavior of your browser, not jQuery. If you see only one div with increased height, then you got it right.

Update:

Also, make sure your

```
"swipe-*"
```

classes are not actually

```
"swipe -*" like "swipe -left"
```

.

```js
function changeSwipe(){
  $(".swipe").height(300);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swipe box">swipe</div>
<div class="swipe-right box">swipe-right</div>
<div class="swipe-whatever box">swipe-whatever</div>
<div class="no-swipe box">no-swipe</div>
<button onclick="changeSwipe();">Run</button>
```